# Probability: Find the largest number of room reservations that this hotel can book

Tags: statistics

There are a total of three-hundred rooms in a hotel. This hotel has adopted an overbooking policy to maximize the usage of lodging capacity. Assume that each potential hotel customer holding a room reservation, independently of other customers, cancels the reservation or simply does not show up at the hotel on a given night with probability $0.2$.

Find largest number of room reservations that this hotel can book and still be at least $95$% sure that everyone who shows up at the hotel will have a room on a given night.

$n= 300, p = 0.2 q = (1-p) = 0.8$
\begin{align}
\text{mean}& = 300*0.2 = 60\\
\text{var}& = 60(0.8)=48\\
\text{sd}& = 6.9282
\end{align}

$Z = 1.645$ since it's $95$% and a one-tailed test

so $300 = X + 1.645*6.9282$, therefore $X = 288.6$, rounded down to $288$ rooms.

I'm wondering if I did the calculations correctly. I have a feeling I did it incorrectly because the question says to use R or Excel to do the computation which means that the calculation part should be tedious if done by hand.

Comment: Are you saying that they should only accept 288 reservations and still fear that 300 people show up? Check the sign again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to find $n$ such that $P(X\leq 300)\geq0.95$, where $X\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(n,0.8)$. You can approximate the distribution of $X$ by $\mathcal{N}(4n/5,4n/25),$ which yields (applying the continuity correction) $$P(X\leq 300)\approx P\left(Z\leq \frac{300.5-4n/5}{\sqrt{4n/25}}\right).$$ The right hand side equals $0.95$ when $(300.5-4n/5)/\sqrt{4n/25}=1.645,$ so 
\begin{align*}
&(300.5-4n/5)/\sqrt{4n/25}=1.645\\
&\Leftrightarrow 300.5-4n/5=2(1.645)\sqrt{n}/5\\
&\Leftrightarrow (300.5)^2-8(300.5)n/5+16n^2/25=4(1.645)^2 n/25\\
&\Leftrightarrow 16n^2/25-(8(300.5)/5+4(1.645)^2/25)n+(300.5)^2=0
\end{align*}
Solving this quadratic equation yields $n=360.019$ and $n=391.908,$ which if we plug in to $(300.5-4n/5)/\sqrt{4n/25}$ give us $1.645$ and $-1.645$, respectively. Thus, we should take $n=360$ (recall that we need to select $n$ to be an integer).

If $X\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(360,0.8),$ then the probability that at least $0.9(300)=270$ rooms will be occupied is $$P(X\geq 270)\approx P\left(Z\geq \frac{269.5-288}{\sqrt{4(360)/25}}\right)=P(Z\geq-2.4376)= 0.9926,$$ or in other words, basically always.

Comment: why is the standard deviation 4n/25?

Comment: The variance is $np(1-p)=n(4/5)(1/5)=4n/25$.

Comment: I was wondering if there is an alternative way to do this on excel or R?

Comment: You could compute the Binomial probability for several different values of $n,$ probably going from $n=300$ to $n=400,$ and stop when you see that $P(X\leq 300)\approx 0.95.$ This approach avoids the normal approximation and the somewhat messy algebra/quadratic equation.